# How can I get rid of "@jsxImportSource @emotion/react" in every file?

Tags: typescript, vite, emotion

I am using Vite + React with TS + emotion in my project.

In CRA env, there is no way to adjust config file without third-party lib. So I have to write `/** @jsxImportSource @emotion/react */` in every tsx file. Okay. That sounds fair.

However, vite allow editing tsconfig file natively. so I tried like this.

```json
// tsconfig.json


{
  "compilerOptions": {
//...
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "jsxImportSource": "@emotion/react",
    "types": ["vite-plugin-svgr/client"]
  },
}

and my vite config file
```

```js
// vite.config.ts

import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react({
      jsxImportSource: "@emotion/react",
      babel: {
        plugins: ["@emotion/babel-plugin"],
      },
    }),
  ],
});
```

But still not working. The thing that makes me angry the most is It works when I add a pragma in tsx file just before!!

```js
/** @jsxImportSource @emotion/react */ <-- emotion works with this
import React from 'react'

//...
```

I really want to remove this pragma in my every files. It looks so ugly and real pain in my ass

Any advice will be great help. Thanks in advance